# PyCharm & Visual Studio Code: importing packages

Tags: python, interpreter

[image] [image]

The code for PyCharm to import the package `extra`:

```
from sys import path
path.append('..\\packages')
import extra.iota
```

The same code in Visual Studio Code rises an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extra'
```

For some reason, to import the `extra` module in Visual Studio Code I need to use this code:

```
from sys import path
path.append('.\\packages')
import extra.iota
```

Can somebody explain why do I need to use one dot instead of two dots in VSC?

Comment: Why don't you just put the `main.py` one level up?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert complete path of package into sys.path.

you can get current path by `__file__`

check below code:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../packages")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(path))
```

Make sure you add absolute path of the package.

Sometimes the working directory is different in many IDE so its better to use complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Get the pathfile by calling **file**

pathfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**))
system.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(pathfile))